# Is there a reference-level implementation of BLAS in C/C++?

Tags: blas, education

The netlib BLAS implementation is an excellent reference, being mostly un-optimized and well documented (e.g. [zgemm](http://www.netlib.org/blas/zgemm.f)).  However, it is in Fortran 77, making it somewhat inaccessible to those with a more modern programming education.  Is there a reference-level implementation of BLAS, like netlib, in C/C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked at [GNU Scientific Library's](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) [implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/cblas)?  I find the source code to be sufficiently readable and the routines are well documented.

Comment: Looks good to me.  The documentation is a bit lacking, but the variable names are chosen well enough that I think its clear.  I'll probably prepend the opening comment of the netlib BLAS routines.  What exactly do you take issue with?  Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 6):

A notable, C language implementation of BLAS is ATLAS. Among useful features:

1. Algebra routines implemented both as straightforward C as well as highly-optimized assembler assisted versions for multiple architectures and variants.
2. The build system features an "auto-tuner" which compiles multiple variants of the ATLAS library to establish which one will be the fastest on the given machine.

http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I looked at ATLAS but missed this.  The path to the reference implementation is "src/blas/reference", with "ref" inserted between the type character and routine name and with character arguments appended.

Answer (score 3):

Netlib also produces [CLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/), which includes BLAS, but it is just the fortran code run through f2c and is therefore a bit clunky (e.g. [zgemm](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/cblas/zgemm.c)).

Answer (score 1):

For a high-performance implementation that is not only among the highest performing (better than 85% of peak on 60 cores of the Intel Xeon Phi), but is also imho the most beautifully written, have a look at BLIS:

https://github.com/flame/blis

Comment: This does not seem like it claims to be a reference-level implementation

Comment: We like to thin of it as a high-performance reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have implementations of some bits of BLAS/LAPACK in [RNP](https://github.com/victorliu/RNP) and [RNP2](https://github.com/victorliu/RNP2).

Comment: This is interesting, but it is definitely post-BLAS and less straight forward than GSL and the reference implementation in ATLAS.

Answer (score -1):

We are currently working on a Massive Open Online Course, "LAFF-On High-Performance Computing" that uses dgemm as the example that leads one through different levels of parallelization: instruction level, OpenMP, MPI.

This is not a reference implementation for the BLAS, but it is a reference for how to code the BLAS (for performance).  To be kept informed, visit [www.ulaff.net](http://www.ulaff.net)